# Programmatically Setting UIButton Font Removes "background Configuration" Section

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

I am attempting to change my font for my UIButton programmatically because it is in a UICollectionView. When I do this however, it removes the "background configuration" in the Attributes Inspector, an example is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZepa.png). The reason why is because the text has to be set to "default" in order for the font to shown from the code. I need that area in order to add a corner style. I have shown my code below In which I have tried to programmatically add a corner style to no luck.

The attempted code specifically is in the "if" statement towards the bottom.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewButtons: UICollectionView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    collectionViewButtons.delegate = self
    collectionViewButtons.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 6 //number of buttons
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonCollectionViewCell

    cell.buttonLive.setTitle("Handling a Breakup", for: .normal) //set button title
cell.buttonLive.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Marker Felt", size: 20)
  _ =  UIButton.Configuration.CornerStyle.large

    
    if indexPath.item == 0 { //first button
        cell.buttonLive.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray //set button background
    }
    else if indexPath.item == 1 { //second button
        cell.buttonLive.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray
        cell.buttonLive.setTitle("Good Work", for: .normal)

    }
    else if indexPath.item == 2 { //3rd button
        cell.buttonLive.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    }
    else { // for remaining buttons
        cell.buttonLive.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    }
    
    return cell
}

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == 0 { // opens any page by clicking button 1
  //      let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "anyVC1") as! ViewController1
//        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
      //      }
      //      else if indexPath.item == 1 {
      //          let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "anyVC2") as! ViewController2
  //      navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
      //      else if indexPath.item == 2 {
      //          let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "anyVC3") as! ViewController3
      //          navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
      //      else {
      //         let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "anyVC4") as! ViewController4
  //      navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
      //  }

    //}
    // You can return any number of buttons by changing return 6 to any required num
```

Answer (score 1):

Use switch statement, this is how your collection view cellForItemAt look like:

```
    cell.myButton.setTitle("Handling a Breakup", for: .normal) //set button title
    cell.myButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Marker Felt", size: 20)
    cell.myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.myButton.clipsToBounds = true
    
    switch indexPath.item {
    case 1:
        cell.myButton.backgroundColor = .link // add your color
        cell.myButton.setTitle("Good Work", for: .normal)
    default:
        cell.myButton.backgroundColor = .white // add your color
    }
    return cell
```